# Using pair/ipair to simplify a lua function

Tags: lua

I have the following code that works:

```
function group1color()
    for _, roomid in ipairs(group1rooms) do
        if roomid == '1+' then
            Controls.room1background.Color = '#dba643'
        end
        if roomid == '2+' then
            Controls.room2background.Color = '#dba643'
        end
        if roomid == '3+' then
            Controls.room3background.Color = '#dba643'
        end
    end
end
```

However, I need to copy the roomid if statement 5 more times, and then copy the function 8 times for eight different room groups. I am trying to figure out if there is a way to simplify this using pairs or ipairs? I am mainly looking for suggestions on how to simplify the iterations in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access global variable by `_G["varname"]`

```
function groupcolor()
   for N = 1, 8 do
      local groupNrooms = _G["group"..N.."rooms"]
      for _, roomid in ipairs(groupNrooms) do
         local M = roomid:match"^(%d+)%+$"
         if M then
            Controls["room"..M.."background"].Color = '#dba643'
         end
      end
   end
end
```